# How to disable Spring's JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect

Tags: spring, aspectj

I'm migrating from Spring 2.5.6 to 3.2.5. The jar spring-aspects-3.2.5 contains the new aspect JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect which translates standard JPA exceptions into Spring exceptions. [It seems to be a Roo-specific aspect](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7649). This aspect gets automatically weaved into repositories (annotated with @Repository). Consequently, standard JPA exceptions are not caught anymore and the application is broken.

How can I exclude JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect from being weaved? If it can't be done, is there any other workaround? Or am I missing some piece of configuration?

I'm using AspectJ 1.7.4 and AspectJ Maven Plugin 1.4.

What I have already gathered:

- [Spring rejected the issue because it's a build issue](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7649)
- [AspectJ Maven Plugin rejected the issue because the AspectJ compiler doesn't support excluding specific aspects from a library](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MASPECTJ-94)

However, I wonder if those pieces of information are up to date.

Comment: Have you tried using @Component instead of @Repository? Simpliest way if want to remove exception translation.

Comment: That would be a simple workaround thank you. However, there could be some other aspects that are wanted and based on the presence of @Repository. I'm not aware of all the consequences removing it could have. Still, it's an idea and I'll give it a try.

Comment: Actually JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect is weaved independently of @Repository, as mentioned in one of the links in my question. I tried nonetheless and it's true.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, upgrade aspectj-maven-plugin to 1.5 and add the complianceLevel tag in the configuration of the plugin (otherwise it will try to compile with java 1.4 compliance by default).
Then you can specify the exclusion through the xmlConfigured property of the aspectj-maven-plugin. This property references a file from your local directory (i.e. where your pom.xml is)

pom.xml exemple :

```xml
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
      <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
      <complianceLevel>${maven.compiler.target}</complianceLevel>
      <xmlConfigured>myCtAspects.xml</xmlConfigured>
      <aspectLibraries>
        <aspectLibrary>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        </aspectLibrary>
      </aspectLibraries>
      <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
      <weaveMainSourceFolder>true</weaveMainSourceFolder>
      <proceedOnError>${maven.aspectj.failOnError}</proceedOnError>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>compile</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>process-resources</phase>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </plugin>
```

Then in myCtAspects.xml file, you just have to specify all the wanted aspects explicitly, including Spring Aspects. In your case:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<aspectj>
    <aspects>
        <!-- Spring Aspects -->
        <aspect name="org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AbstractInterfaceDrivenDependencyInjectionAspect"/>
        <aspect name="org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect"/>
        <aspect name="org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AnnotationTransactionAspect"/>        
        <!-- Your Application Aspects -->
    </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

Comment: Arg, it actually was said [here](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7649) but I missed it because AspectJ Maven Plugin did not support it at the time. Thanks.

Comment: I try and it seems to be OK : there is no JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect  refence in the compiled code

Comment: Wait, it worked but it disabled all aspects ^^'. Seems like I need to declare every aspect I want to use in the XML.

Comment: You are rigth. It is necessary to list all needed aspects : spring and application aspects. I updated the example above.

Comment: This answer helped me. I know a lot about AspectJ, but `-xmlConfigured` is totally undocumented for *Ajc*. Thus, I have just created a [bug ticket](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=455014) for it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use aop-autoproxy's include proprety with some invert regexp (something like `^((?! JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect).)*$`).

Comment: That would work if Spring was in charge of the AOP stuff. In my case it's AspectJ, with compile-time weaving.

Comment: if so you should use "exclude" configuration on you aspectj-maven plugin configuration.

Comment: This only works for aspects that are part of the module being compiled. It doesn't work for aspects residing in external libraries.