# How do you ignore AspectJ compiler warnings for certain aspects with Maven

Tags: spring, maven, aspectj, spring-aspects

If you use the AspectJ compiler with an Aspect library such as Springs and you do not have any classes that match a particular Aspect you get:

```
[WARNING] advice defined in org.springframework.orm.jpa.aspectj.JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
```

But for this particular project I don't need this aspect as well as some other aspects.

It seems you can configure the warnings with -Xlint but it looks like you can only turn off all the warning for advice that doesn't match (`adviceDidNotMatch=ignore`). What I really want to do is exclude certain Aspects such as `org.springframework.orm.jpa.aspectj.JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect`. I can't seem to find an example of excluding an aspect.

Comment: I think it is valuable information to know that an advice does not match. Suppressing warnings is rarely a good idea. Imagine that suddenly the advice does match because your code base has changed. How will you be able to tell the difference?

Comment: @kriegaex I'm not sure you understand the problem. Of course its valuable but its a false warning as I'm not using that particular aspect and I know that I'm not using it. So now I have WARNING messages always in my build and thus have a higher probability of ignoring real WARNING messages. But to your point I do want to know about warnings for other aspects but you can only disable all of the warnings right now. Part of the problem is that `spring-aspects` includes aspects that are often irrelevant to projects. Not all projects use JPA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are ready to list each single aspect to be used in some kind of whitelist, you can use

```
ajc -xmlConfigured myConfig.xml ...
```

or the corresponding [AspectJ Maven Plugin parameter](http://mojo.codehaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html#xmlConfigured). Why this is not listed in the *ajc* usage help, I have no idea. I have never used this option before, but just tested it now and can confirm that it works. It should be in *ajc* since 1.6.9 and in *AspectJ Maven* since 1.5.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20658196/1082681) for more information and a sample XML file. A minimal sample is also listed [here](http://aspectj.2085585.n4.nabble.com/aspectj-maven-plugin-and-xmlConfigured-tp2274190p2275390.html).

**Please note:** The option and XML file name have to be explicitly specified. Unlike *aop.xml* in LTW mode there is no file with a magic name to be picked up automatically for CTW. This fact was mentioned by AspectJ maintainer Andy Clement [here](http://aspectj.2085585.n4.nabble.com/aspectj-maven-plugin-and-xmlConfigured-tp2274190p2286319.html).

**Update:** AJC option `-xmlConfigured` is now documented [here](https://eclipse.dev/aspectj/doc/latest/devguide/ajc.html#ajc_options:%7E:text=%2DxmlConfigured%20%3Cfiles%3E).

Comment: **Update:** AJC option `-xmlConfigured` is now documented [here](https://eclipse.dev/aspectj/doc/latest/devguide/ajc.html#ajc_options:~:text=%2DxmlConfigured%20%3Cfiles%3E).

Answer (score 3):

Just to add, there is possibility to change log level for adviceDidNotMatch for aspectj-maven-plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <artifactId>1.5</artifactId>
    <configuration>
          <Xlint>adviceDidNotMatch=error,noGuardForLazyTjp=ignore</Xlint>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Possible values: ignore/warning/error

related jira: https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MASPECTJ-126

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

AFAIK, you can only add external aspects to `ajc` with -`aspectpath` that will include all aspects in the jars, so there is no way to add a jar with aspects but excluding some one unless you unzip, delete and create a new jar.

Comment: I always thought aop.xml was for load time weaving and not compile time weaving. I shall look into that though.

Comment: @AdamGent: You are right, *aop.xml* is only used for LTW. But it seems that José has updated his answer, I just read it now. It no longer contains any references to *aop.xml*.

Comment: Well the issue is the `spring-aspects` jar comes from maven so its unlikely I'm going to repackage it. I guess I'll just have to turn off the warning. I guess there is always unit tests.

Comment: To my own surprise, there is an undocumented way to exclude aspects, simply by not *in*cluding them into an XML config file. See my answer about `-xmlConfigured`.