# Is it possible to exclude aspects with io.freefair.aspectj.post-compile-weaving?

Tags: gradle, aspectj, freefair-aspectj

I have a Gradle 7.3.3 aspect library and a Gradle 7.3.3 project which consumes that library. I am applying the `io.freefair.aspectj.post-compile-weaving` Gradle plugin in the project.

```java
plugins {
    id 'io.freefair.aspectj.post-compile-weaving' version '6.3.0'
}
```

I am then adding the library to the project as an aspect dependency.

```java
dependencies {
    aspect 'com.example:my-aspect-lib:0.0.1'
}
```

Aside from the library aspects that I want to weave post-compile, the project itself has aspects that I want Spring AOP to handle at runtime. Those aspects must not be woven post-compile. However, the default behavior of `post-compile-weaving` is to weave all aspects in the project.

I have tried quite a few different iterations of ajc configuration, including messing with `compilerArgs`, but so far I have not been able to exclude the project aspects from post-compile weaving.

```java
compileJava {
    ajc {
        options {
            aspectpath.minus files()
            aspectpath.setFrom configurations.aspect
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to exclude aspects with the `post-compile-weaving` plugin?

*I also asked this question [here](https://github.com/freefair/gradle-plugins/discussions/471) but as of this post have not yet received any response.*

Comment: Welcome to SO. Do yourself a favour and provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when asking questions. The benefit will be better and quicker answers. In this case, for example, I know a lot about AspectJ and also know how to build with Maven, but I am not a Gradle user. I think I can look into it and help you, if I have an example project reproducing your problem, but I do not feel so inclined to prepare an example multi-module project from scratch and learn Gradle just in order to help you.

Answer (score 1):

*This is a general answer, not specific to Freefair or even Gradle:*

The AspectJ compiler has an undocumented option `-xmlConfigured` by which you can specify an XML file similar to the `aop.xml` file used to configure load-time weaving (LTW). The best overview of how to use it you can find in the [AspectJ documentation bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=455014) I raised in back in 2014. Just read through it and follow some of the links I provided.

If the Freefair post-compile plugin supports some way of adding custom compiler options, I think this is what you want, because in the XML file you can explicitly specify which aspects the compiler should use. All others, it will ignore.

---

**Update:** See also my other answers concerning `-xmlConfigured`:

- [How to use on the AJC command line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27435109/1082681)
- [How to use from Eclipse IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57121636/1082681)
- [How to use in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20658196/1082681)

That should give you enough information to adapt it to Gradle.

**Update:** AJC option `-xmlConfigured` is now documented [here](https://eclipse.dev/aspectj/doc/latest/devguide/ajc.html#ajc_options:%7E:text=%2DxmlConfigured%20%3Cfiles%3E).

Comment: **Update:** AJC option `-xmlConfigured` is now documented [here](https://eclipse.dev/aspectj/doc/latest/devguide/ajc.html#ajc_options:~:text=%2DxmlConfigured%20%3Cfiles%3E).